# Can you take out the exponent from an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to do a simple integration and I was wondering if this is possible or if it breaks a law:

$$\int { \frac { 1 }{ \cos^{ 2 }4x }  } \, dx\\ ={ \left[ \int { \frac { 1 }{  \cos 4x }  } \,dx \right]  }^{ 2 }$$

Any hints on how I can approach to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't. Hint to solve the integral: $\tan(x)'=...$

Comment: can you take out the exponent from $\int {x^2\;dx}$

Answer (score 9):

No, that's not a valid manipulation - consider $\int 1^2 dx$ vs $\left( \int 1 dx \right)^2$.

This particular integral can be computed starting from the fact $$\frac{d \tan(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}.$$

Answer (score 4):

No, you the integral of a squared function is not equal to the square of the integral of a the function. That means in this case:

$$\int { \frac { 1 }{ { \cos }^{ 2 }4x }  } dx \neq{ \left[ \int { \frac { 1 }{ { \cos }4x }  } dx \right]  }^{ 2 }$$

Hint: $$\int { \frac { 1 }{ { \cos }^{ 2 }4x }  } dx = \int \sec^2 4x \,dx = \frac 14\int \frac{d}{dx}(\tan 4x) \,dx$$

Comment: This needs another +1!

Answer (score 0):

What is the derivative of tanx?
Now what is the derivative of tan(4x) ?
How do you "compensate" for that Chain Rule?

Comment: It is not a new question. The author is asking for hints to answer his question. And that's what I have done. I did not want to post the answer, because that defeats the purpose. The author then might as well put it in Wolfram. Perhaps I should have put it as "comment" rather than "answer"